# How do you write a JavaScript function that can be extended with out modifying original function

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a quiz program that has multiple different quiz types like Truefalse, multiple choice, etc.

so I could write the code like this

```
function setQuiz(){
  if(quizType == trueFalse){ trueFalseQuiz() }
  else if (quizType == multichoice){multichoiceQuiz()}
  //etc...
}

function trueFalseQuiz(){ //do this}
function multichoiceQuiz(){ //do this}
```

problem is I would have to change the original function each time I want to add to new quiz type and my understanding is that this is bad practice. So how do I extend this without changing the original calling function.

Comment: You should look into `class` and inheritance concepts

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ideal case for what's called higher order function. Here's an example:

```js
function trueFalseQuiz() {
  // some code
}

function setQuiz(quiz) {
  return quiz();
}

setQuiz(trueFalseQuiz);
```

I didn't get from your question how `quizType` is defined. If you control this variable, I'd recommend to put function inside. This way it'll be even shorter, maybe something like this:

```js
const quizType = trueFalseQuiz;
// or
const quiz = {
  type: 'trueFalse',
  start: trueFalseQuiz
};

function setQuiz() {
  return quizType();
  // or
  return quiz.start()
}

setQuiz();
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Anurag` said, you should go and learn `Inheritance`. Concept of the `factory`, `Interface`.

Here is a `basic sample`, how it should be done

```js
class FakeInterface {
  isCorrect() {
    throw Error("You should override it");
  }
  postAnswer(answer) {
    throw Error("You should override it");
  }
}
class TrueFalseQuize {
  constructor() {
    this.quize = "this is boolean quize";
  }
  postAnswer(answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
  }
  isCorrect() {
    return this.answer === "boolean";
  }
}
class MultiChoiseQuize extends FakeInterface {
  constructor() {
    this.quize = "this is multi quize";
  }
  postAnswer(answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
  }
  isCorrect() {
    return this.answer === "multi";
  }
}

class SomeThingElse extends FakeInterface {

}

class QuizeFactory extends FakeInterface {
  constructor() {
    throw Error("You should not create isntance");
  }
}
QuizeFactory.getInstance = function (isBoolean) {
  if (isBoolean) return new TrueFalseQuize();
  return new MultiChoiseQuize();
};
const trueFalse = QuizeFactory.getInstance(true);
const multi = QuizeFactory.getInstance(true);

trueFalse.postAnswer(true);
console.log(trueFalse);
multi.postAnswer("multi");
console.log(multi);
const something = new SomeThingElse(); 
console.log(something.isCorrect()); // Error here
```

```css
.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```